# Can noises similar to crickets be made well underwater?

Tags: creature-design, language

So I have this sea creature. It's lower half is lobster-like. It's upper half sort of humanoid. On its lower torso area it has ridges and stuff and multiple pairs of small tentacles to scrape the ridges. I believe it's called stridulation. How well does this work underwater? Does it carry well? How would variations in the stridulating mechanisms create a wide variety of sounds usable as a language?

Comment: Does it have to be made by stridulation? Because if not, then the answer is quite obviously yes, cricket noises can be made underwater; just record a cricket and reproduce the noise with a suitable loudspeaker.

Comment: Have you ever listened to dolphin, or other sea life recordings? There are a lot of aquatic animals that use sound in many different ways.

Answer (score 3):

Many underwater animals, from [invertebrates](https://dosits.org/animals/sound-production/how-do-marine-invertebrates-produce-sounds/) to [catfish](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4608557?seq=1), use stridulation to produce sound.  [Corixids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022191083900057), aquatic insects also known as water boatmen, use various pulse patterns to communicate, not unlike crickets.

Sound carries differently underwater than in the air (notably it moves faster and travels further) but there's no reason why a sea creature couldn't produce a cricket noise.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that underwater invertebrates were creating a whole chorus. It's so cool when some wild sci-fi concept turns out to exist in the real world.